# Files in aws s3 bucket are not public after they are synced by aws cli

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

How are you.
I am syncing react.js web application build dir with aws s3 bucket.
When I upload files inside build directory into s3 manually by entering amazon console (https://s3.console.aws.amazon.com/), all the uploaded files are public so when I visit endpoint it shows website well (I am using s3 for static website hosting)

But if I sync this with aws cli

```
aws s3 sync build/ s3://mybucketnamehere --delete
```

I can see all uploaded new files in bucket, but those are all access denied so It gives me 403 error when I enter the site.

This is policy

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": [
                "s3:DeleteObject",
                "s3:DeleteObjectTagging",
                "s3:DeleteObjectVersion",
                "s3:DeleteObjectVersionTagging",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:GetObjectAcl",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::mybucketnamehere",
                "arn:aws:s3:::mybucketnamehere/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Notice that you should both configure the site itself as public read, and use public-read on the sync CLI. See full example in this post: https://runkiss.blogspot.com/2021/10/build-s3-website.html

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The right answer is: don't use S3 to serve your static files. You should set up a Cloudfront distribution to serve these files, as it gives you numerous advantages.

If for some reason you can't use Cloudfront, you can add `--acl public-read` to your command:

```
aws s3 sync build/ s3://mybucketnamehere --delete --acl public-read
```

Comment: How would you upload files via CloudFront? S3 and CloudFront have different purposes, CloudFront can serve S3 files, not sure what you mean by "use Cloufront", you still need to provide those files to S3.

Comment: There are two use-cases. 1. Upload and storage 2. Serve files. S3 is made for storage and Cloudfront is more appropriate for distribution.